# Gatsby: Changing Default Path Names

Tags: reactjs, path, gatsby

I'm just starting to use Gatsby and playing with the following template: [yellowcake](https://github.com/thriveweb/yellowcake/)

I would like to change the default path names (specifically posts), but after trying to change the "posts" in the config.yml, but any page I try to access with the new path crashes. I would basically like to change the following:

domain.com/**posts**/some-article-in-the-content-posts-folder

to

domain.com/**my-custom-path**/some-article-in-the-content-posts-folder

Comment: can you share you gatsby-node.js

Comment: Yes, it is the same as the way the template came:
[https://github.com/thriveweb/yellowcake/blob/master/gatsby-node.js](https://github.com/thriveweb/yellowcake/blob/master/gatsby-node.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from replacing the path in `config.yml` you also need to change the setting in `src/cms/cms.js` to below

```
CMS.registerPreviewTemplate('my-custom-path', ({ entry }) => (
  <SinglePostTemplate {...entry.toJS().data} />
))
```

**P.S.** Clean your gatsby cache and rebuild the app once you made the change.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try and play around with both the config.yml and the cms.js. Currently, the cms.js looks like this: [https://github.com/thriveweb/yellowcake/blob/master/static/admin/config.yml](https://github.com/thriveweb/yellowcake/blob/master/static/admin/config.yml)

Comment: Let me know if the above solution works for you or not

Comment: I get an error saying: Cannot read property 'component---src-templates-single-post-js' of undefined which it says is coming from .cache/loader.js

I see this error when I attempt to access any custom path page.

Comment: Could you try to clean up the gatsby cache and rebuild it

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked. I will mark your answer as the solution. I needed to clean the Gatsby cache.

Comment: To help anyone in the future who is trying to customize the paths in this template, I made the following edits to change "posts" to a custom path name: edited all instances of "posts" to my desired path name in config.yml, edited "posts" in cms.js to my desired path name, and edited "posts" to my desired path name in the SinglePost.js' pageQuery section. After I changed these, I then typed "gatsby clean" in terminal to clear the cache followed by "npm run build" and "npm run start" to see the changes without issue.